# Sqlite can't attach database to main

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I am kinda new to sqlite3 I am toying with Ruby on Rails and I wanted to have more info about the command .dump in the sqlite3 console. But I forgot to add .help at the end so It kinda removed the link between my main and the file it was attached to.

Now I am trying to attach my file to my main database but it always says;

```
"Error: database main is already in use"
```

what I was seeing using the command .database was looking like this

```
seq  name             file
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             C:\xampp\htdocs\FirstProject\first_app\db\development.sqli
1    temp
```

but now it kinda look like that :

[image http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/8922/ss20120212173726.png](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/8922/ss20120212173726.png)

I have been looking on the internet for a little while now and I can't really find an answer to that problem. I finally rake db:setup and my migration came back and everything but it did not fix the problem with sqlite3.

The up side is that I can still add things via rails console but I can't list or check the content of my database via sqlite3 prompt command.

So if anyone have an idea for my problem it will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from here http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

```
The database-names 'main' and 'temp' refer to the main database and the database used for temporary tables. The main and temp databases cannot be attached or detached.
```

Just try and use the file as a parameter to your sqlite3 command. It will open the file.

On here's more info  `attach database`  or `detach database`
http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg12.htm

---

```
sqlite> attach "testdb" as test1;
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file
---  ---------------  ------------------------------------------------------
0    main
2    test1            C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\testdb
sqlite> .quit

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>sqlite3 test
SQLite version 3.7.10 2012-01-16 13:28:40
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file
---  ---------------  ------------------------------------------------------
0    main             C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\test
```

Comment: now im running with
http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/8986/ss20120212181029.png
thats how it looks like when I type .database, from the link you posted if I understand well I will not be able to list the tables from command like .tables. unless it's stored in the temp ???

Comment: you are running with what? :)

Comment: Well I attached my old file to sqlite3 but still can't see table if I type .tables but I can insert data with the rails console so I guess everything is alright but not back to the way it was, with Main linked directly to my file.

Comment: aahhhh 
after looking at your nice exemple on top I type
sqlite3 developement.sqlite3 and now it looks like this

http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/926/ss20120212184543.png

everything seems to be normal now